# AngularJS: Email verification bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does the follow code:

```
<div id="frontpage" layout layout-align="center center">
<md-card class="padding-10 signup-form">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="frontpage.signup_email">
  </md-input-container>
   <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="!frontpage.signup_email.$valid">signup</md-button>
</md-card>
```

Produce this:

### [image]

It is clearly a valid email, and yet the button is still disabled. Have been going at this for at least an hour with no luck.

Comment: its shuld be a form name and field name,  e.g. form name="frontpage", input type email name="signup_email".

Comment: Wow, thank you. Can't belive i missed this.